# Pygame random map generation

Tags: python, dictionary, pygame

I've been working on writing a game in Python using the Pygame module.
right now I'm trying to generate a map. I want to generate a large world and save it as some sort of file then reuse it every time the game loads. I probably want to write a different program preferably in python to generate the world and then keep using the same world. I can't just make it completely random because I wouldn't get landscape just random tiles so how do I do that? I have a few tile images like "terrain/grass.png, terrain/water.png".

I tried some things like:

```
screen.blit(water, [river_startx, river_starty])
screen.blit(water, [river_startx, river_starty + 32])
screen.blit(water, [river_startx + 32, river_starty + 32])
screen.blit(water, [river_startx + 32, river_starty + 64])
screen.blit(water, [river_startx + 32, river_starty + 96])
```

And I made a bit of a river but that would take forever to do manually.

Collin N.

Comment: This question has much less to do with Pygame and Python and much more to do with a very general 'how to program' approach. It really does not feel like a great fit for this community.

Comment: What do you mean? it looks to me like it has everything to do with python and pygame its a question about writing a map generator in python for pygame. how do I make it "a great fit for this community". I've been writing python for years and I know "how to program" I just have a specific question.

Comment: Writing a map generator is not a topic specific to pygame. Writing a map generator is a topic specific to game development. Writing a map generator is not a question-and-answer type of topic. Writing a map generator is at the very least "hour-long tutorial" type of topic, and might even be "thesis project" type of topic.

Comment: Isn't it specific to python if I want to write it in python?

Comment: I don't really want to engage in debate about this; it looks like I'm not the only person who feels the question is not a good fit. A Python question might be something like "I've written this code to read map data out of a file, but for some reason it isn't working; here's the code and here's the output."

Comment: I would advise you to use something like Tiled and then use a maploader for pygame, may seem like a plug but it would be quite easy to design a large map, make some copies and modify each, then randomly choose between these when choosing the map to load

Answer (score 1):

Now that I've made my comment, I feel a little bad that I didn't give you more constructive suggestions toward solving your problem.

You are going to want to store your map in some kind of data format. You should figure out what that data format will be, and how you want to read it back in. The possibilities here are without end: you could use a database, you could use a data file, you could use source code, etcetera. But you will need to store the map in some kind of data format, and you're not going to get very far if you are using a graphics context as your data format.

How you build your map is part of your game logic, and not necessarily part of your programming logic. That is, you might define rules like "don't start a river unless I'm in the mountains; don't stop a river unless I'm at a body of water" or "a tile is much more likely to be a mountain if it is nearby other mountains". Programmatic map design is a very big topic in game programming, and you might find some useful discussion in game development communities. Try http://www.pixelprospector.com/the-big-list-of-indie-game-development-forums/ as a possible place to start.

Comment: Thanks, I'm thinking probably a text file like: g g g g w g m m m

Comment: See this too: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31241/random-map-generation